# How to populate the values of XML in JSP?

Tags: java, xml, jsp

I am new to the Java development. I need to populate XML fields in a JSP page.

I didn't do with JDBC actually i have written the Mysql wrapper in C

it executes the query and return the table value as XML.

Help me how to populate the XML fields in JSP?

how to read the XML file using JDBC ResultSet?

Will be much helpful

thanks

krishna

The XML File from C Wrapper

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<test>
<TableRow>
<name>
krishna
</name>
<Age>
30
</Age>
</TableRow>
<TableRow>
<name>
kumar
</name>
<Age>
40
</Age>
</TableRow>
<TableRow>
<name>
kumar
</name>
<Age>
40
</Age>
</TableRow>
</test>
```

Comment: You want to return the results of a MySQL query in XML format?

Comment: What does your current JSP page look like?

Comment: In C code i will pass the query string
it will connect to the Mysql database and 
executes the query and return the table values
in XML format.
I want to read the XML file using JDBC Resultset
for populating it in a JSP page.

Answer (score 2):

To handle XML as a [java.sql.ResultSet](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) you need to use a [javax.sql.rowset.WebRowSet](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/sql/rowset/WebRowSet.html).

Chances are the XML your C wrapper is generating isn't in a format that [javax.sql.rowset.WebRowSet](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/sql/rowset/WebRowSet.html) will understand so you'll have to do a transformation using XSLT.

With regards to rendering fields in a JSP, use the JSTL [c:out](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/index.html) tag.  If you want you JSP itself to be XML you need to set the `content-type` to `text/html` using the following page directive:

```
<%@page contentType="text/xml" %>
```

Comment: thanks nick
will update you if i get any errors and exceptions